# in GDI+ how to pass graphics to image

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

In `C#` I am drawing things on panel using `creategraphics`, 
and I need to pass these things to an image or a bitmap, how can I do that?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw directly to an `Image` by calling [`Graphics.FromImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx).

You can draw a `Control` to a `Bitmap` by calling [`Control.DrawToBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx)

---

By the way, the correct way to draw to a control is to handle its [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event and draw to `e.Graphics` in it.  If you draw a control using `CreateGraphics`, it will be erased when the control is redrawn (eg, if you drag a window over it pre-Vista)